# Can't boot Ubuntu 64bit

Tags: 12.04, boot, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run update-grub if I can't boot into linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176279/how-can-i-run-update-grub-if-i-cant-boot-into-linux)

I downloaded Ubuntu 64bit and installed it from a CD. Everything went fine the partitions were correct but when I start my computer there is no option for  I have a system of 8GB Ram, GTX 670 and i5 3570. I also have a durable mothereboard. I want to choose between the Ubuntu and Windows before booting. I know that the bios can help and maybe you have to tell it where to search to boot. But I don't know of this stuff and I want details how to do it.

Comment: Is this a dule-boot with windows ? If so when you see bios screen hold the shift key to start grub ? This may help

Comment: What options are you looking for? Please update your answer to provide more detailed information.

Comment: I want to choose between the Ubuntu and Windows before booting. I know that the bios can help and maybe you have to tell it where to search to boot. But I don't know of this stuff and I want details how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the live CD. Open the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

-Press Enter - Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then open boot repair. Perform recommended repairs. If that does not fix it then paste the link here for the boot summary.

Comment: when I type the first line it says that it needs a repository as argument. I typed the name of the disk where it says ppa but it still tells me the same. @Varun Schweinsteiger Venkatesh

Comment: Okay with BIOS you can choose which device to boot with.It could be hard disk,USB drive or Optical CD drive. The Bootloader shows the different boot options. Do you Know if you are using BIOS or UEFI? UEFI has a very different boot manager. But I still don't get why you have the repo problem. Try it again,if that doesn't work, download the iso from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/ .Burn a bootable Iso and start it on start up by Selecting DVD drive as your first boot Device(in BIOS). The startup CD will automatically run bot repair and should fix your problems.

Comment: I am using atheros boot agent. Where is the option to choose from where to boot? @Varun Schweinsteiger Venkatesh

Comment: If you Booting from A USB Stick in BIOS select USB device as first boot device. Since you're a little bit new and confused to all this   I would recommend you to burn a bootable ISO of Boot-repair which I mentioned above. It will automatically repair your boot if you are able to properly set your BIOS boot device. this here http://www.hiren.info/pages/bios-boot-cdrom should help you understand how to boot from CD or USB .