# How can I run update-grub if I can't boot into linux?

Tags: server, grub2, boot-failure

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 onto an old HP DL320 G2. This has a ATI Rage XL video card built in. Everything seems to install okay, but I'm having problems with booting.

Once the server starts booting, the screen goes black after posting, and nothing else is displayed-- no grub menu, error messages, etc. (I left it like that all night). If I hold down the [shift] key, 'loading Grub' is displayed, but once again nothing after that.

I have read several suggestions on how to fix this (and similar problems) by modifying the `/etc/default/grub` file and then running `sudo update-grub`. How can I run `update-grub` if it doesn't seem to be booting all the way into linux?

I think there must be an error occurring, preventing it from fully starting. However, I can't see anything to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from the live CD. Open the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

-Press Enter 
- Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

The open boot repair. Perform recommended repairs. If that does not fix it then paste the link here for the boot summary.

Comment: That worked! However, when I rebooted after setting up my users, once again nothing was displayed. Fortunately, I should be able to do everything through SSH now.

Comment: Glad that I could help.